# why i am getting rows with null values when i am trying to create view from json file in spark with java

Tags: java, apache-spark

i am reading Json file and creating view in spark with java when i am trying to display it was displaying two extra row starting and ending with null values

i have tried with different options line multi line true but it's not working

```
 class Something
 {
   public void DoSomething() {
    SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("jsonreader")
    .master("local[4]").getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> jsondataset = session.read()
                                     .json("G:\\data\\employee.json");
    jsondataset.select("id","name","age").show();
      }
}

+----+-------+----+
|  id|   name| age|
+----+-------+----+
|null|   null|null|
|1201| satish|  25|
|1202|krishna|  28|
|null|   null|null|
+----+-------+----+


{
   {"id" : "1201", "name" : "satish", "age" : "25"}
   {"id" : "1202", "name" : "krishna", "age" : "28"}
}
```

is my json file and i am getting out put rows with null values like above
can any one help me why i am getting like this

Comment: thanks arvind but i want read json file in that format only

Answer (score 0):

The extra curly brackets are causing this. You will have to handle it either before reading JSON or after reading it ie through spark. Also the NULLs are read as strings not exactly NULL. Below is my workaround, the filter condition will uniquely identify these faulty rows due the "null" being string. :

```
jsondataset = jsondataset.select("age","id","name").filter("age <> 'null'")
jsondataset.show()

// Result 
//   +---+----+-------+
//   |age|id  |name   |
//   +---+----+-------+
//   |25 |1201|satish |
//   |28 |1202|krishna|
//   +---+----+-------+
```

Comment: Hey @ Manoj Kumar please upvote the solution if it worked for you.